# ngx-swimlane and html2canvas - Image background cannot be transparent even when is set to null or default

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html2canvas, html2pdf

Currentl, I'm playing with ngx-swimlane charts and converting them to pdf.
In the below example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/grpd-bar-chart-download-pdf

whenever I try to change background to some color it stays black.

I tried:

use backgroundColor: undefined, backgroundColor: null,
background: undefined, background: null, (also tried with transparent properties). Above you can see the exact code.
Also tried to set background color in css.

```
html2canvas(chart, {
        height: 500,
        width: 1000,
        scale: 3,
        backgroundColor: null,
        logging: false,
        onclone: (document) => {
        document.getElementById('chart').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Whenever I tried the rendered background color was black! Has anyone faced the same issue and successfully got rid of black background ?

Any advice appreciated!